# What is the best way to build C/C++ program in open source community?

Tags: c++, c, build, autoconf, automake

We have a very old and big project which is mainly written by C (and a small piece of C++), and it can be built in both Linux and Windows. Currently, we write all the Makefiles in this project manually which I think is not good.

Now we want to make this project fully open source. However, before that, we want to enhance the way to build this project. So I'd like to know what is the best/popular way in open source community to build such project? I know a bit about autoconf/antomake which seems existing there for quit a long time, just wondering if any new and better way to build C/C++ project come up?

Thanks!

Comment: In your opinion, why are manually created Makefiles 'not good'.

Comment: Using `autoconf` seems to be a broadly accepted and well working way. Though it's quite complicated to set up, compared to CMake or similar build systems,

Comment: I think the standard sequence is 'configure', 'make', and 'make install'.  Is this an option you are contemplating?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I have to agree, this sequence doesn't necessarily had to be created with the `autoconf` tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most "open source" way would be to retool the compiler chain to use autotools.

Basically it permits compilation on one of a number of "unknown" systems by detecting the need libraries and their locations and then writing the makefiles to match the platform.

For C and C++ it is a very good match.

If you want to "push the envelope" Apache's Maven can also compile C and C++ with the NAR plugin.  Personally, I really like Apache's Maven; however, if you are not versed with it, NAR plus "learning maven" will be quite a challenge.  Meanwhile, everyone who's installed from source on a Linux box quickly becomes familiar with auotmake's "configure; make; make install" routine, so using Maven to do this is really a bit "outside the box".

There is also CMake; however, the benefits of CMake don't really strike me as overwhelmingly different from the more mature autotools tool chain.  That said, CMake is a pretty nice setup, which becomes more complex (and matches the automake environment more and more) as it has to support the issues that a mature tool-chain like automake support.

All in all, I'd say stick with autoconf/autotools/automake.  There are plenty of examples, and while you might have to leverage the M4 macro language, every part of the build system is readable, and can be leveraged to create your own custom extensions.